# Set Validation Message on Control Manually

Tags: c#, silverlight, validation, xaml

I am trying to set the Validation Message  manually without the common practice where you throw an exception.

I know I can manually change the state of the control as follows:

```
VisualStateManager.GoToState(this.TextBox, "InvalidFocused", true);
```

Now I just want to set the error message manually... Anyone know how?

I know this is a HACK but it's something I need at this point.

Any ideas???

Comment: Can you show code or be more specific on how your error message is set up?  There's many ways to do validation in XAML

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't understand how you have your errormessage set up.  For example you can have an ErrorTemplate that would have textblocks in them, which you pass an errorResponse object to containing an error message.  But that doesn't sound like the route you've taken.  I need to understand what "Element" displays the errormessage (textblock, label, msgbox), before I can help with how you would set it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution....found [this](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/87618/202683.aspx) post.

```
public object Value
{
   get { return (object)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
   set 
   {
      if (value.ToString() == "testing")
      {
          SetControlError(this, "This is an invalid value.");
      }
      else
      {
          ClearControlError(this);
          SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
      }
   }
}

public void ClearControlError(Control control)
{
   BindingExpression b = control.GetBindingExpression(Control.TagProperty);

   if (b != null)
   {
      ((ControlValidationHelper)b.DataItem).ThrowValidationError = false;
      b.UpdateSource();
   }
}       


 public void SetControlError(Control control, string errorMessage)
 {
    ControlValidationHelper validationHelper =
                new ControlValidationHelper(errorMessage);

    control.SetBinding(Control.TagProperty, new Binding("ValidationError")
    {
       Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
       NotifyOnValidationError = true,
       ValidatesOnExceptions = true,
       UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.Explicit,
       Source = validationHelper
    });

    // this line throws a ValidationException with your custom error message;
    // the control will catch this exception and switch to its "invalid" state
    control.GetBindingExpression(Control.TagProperty).UpdateSource();
}
```

// Helper Class

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
public class ControlValidationHelper
{
    private string _message;

    public ControlValidationHelper(string message)
    {
        if (message == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("message");
        }

        _message = message;
        ThrowValidationError = true;
    }

    public bool ThrowValidationError
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public object ValidationError
    {
        get { return null; }
        set
        {
            if (ThrowValidationError)
            {
                throw new ValidationException(_message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a ton for helping me figure this out. There is a vast shortage of tutorials on how to do advanced stuff in Silverlight. It's also unfortunate how every link to the silverlight forums doesn't seem to work anymore.